# How to alter classpath for Java executable in ctx.actions.run?

Tags: bazel

In my Java-based Bazel project I use a code generator written in Java. The generator is part of the root project, and used in sub-projects as well.

What I want to achieve is to include the output of the root project (a .jar file) as a dependency for the code generation in sub-projects to grant the code generator  access to all compiled files of the root project (through the classpath). Is that possible in Bazel?

What I see is that the classpath for key generation in the child project only includes the dependencies of the code generator binary (//parent:SettingsGenerator in the script below).

In my custom rule I invoke the code generator basically like this:

```
def _generate_settings(ctx):
    ...
    ctx.actions.run(
        inputs = [ctx.file._src] + [ctx.files.deps],
        outputs = [keys, settings, loader],
        mnemonic = "GenKeysAndSettings",
        arguments = [args],
        executable = ctx.executable._tool,
    )
    return [DefaultInfo(
        files=depset([keys, settings, loader]),
        runfiles=ctx.runfiles(files=ctx.files.deps)
    )]

gen_settings = rule(
    implementation = _generate_settings,
    attrs = {
        "lang": attr.string(),
        "deps": attr.label_list(
            allow_files = True
        ),
        "_tool": attr.label(
            cfg = "host",
            executable = True,
            default = Label("//parent:SettingsGenerator"),
        ),
        "_src": attr.label(
            single_file = True,
            default = Label("//parent:Name")
        ),
    }
)
```

The parent project BUILD:

```
load("//parent:settings.bzl", "gen_settings")

gen_settings(
    name = "GenerateSettings",
    lang = ""
)
java_library(
    name = "parent",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]) + [
        ":GenerateSettings",
    ],
    ...
)
java_binary(
    name = "SettingsGenerator",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/SettingsGenerator.java"]),
    main_class = "my.company.SettingsGenerator",
    ...
)
```

The child project BUILD:

```
gen_settings(
    name = "GenerateSettings",
    lang = "Java",
    deps = ["//parent"]
)
...
```

My workaround is to include the .jar file as input and use a custom classloader in the generator. But it would be nice if I could control the classpath directly from Bazel.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you need Java-Skylark interoperability. You can check the blog-post on this topic [1] and the documentation [2].

You should return a JavaInfo provider from your Skylark rule.


[1]  https://blog.bazel.build/2017/03/07/java-sandwich.html
[2] https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/java_common.html

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointer. At first glance I'm not sure whether this will satisfy my needs, but I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Java-Skylark interoperability does not seem like the solution. The only thing I found which alters the classpath is to change the dependencies of the executable which might not always be desirable.
In the future it might be possible through a custom FilesToRunProvider, see https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7187